# Bitfinex to Poloniex - Payment ID

Tags: payment-id

Newbie here..

I have some XMR in bifinex and want to transfer them to Poloniex. Bitfinex asks for a Payment ID while Poloniex just shows an XMR address and not a payment ID. Where can I check it in Poloniex?

Please help.

Thanks
TnnJ

Answer (score 1):

Payment ID is provided by the receiver of funds. In poloniex, It can be the case that they use Integrated addresses (where the payment ID its already attached to the public address). If its the case, you dont need to put Payment ID in bitfinex when sending to polo. [Looking at this tweet](https://twitter.com/poloniex/status/872296670586916865?lang=es) seems to corroborate the above description. I hope this helps. Kind regards...